# React native Expo expo app could not connect t sever

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

i have been scanning the bar code using expo go on my phone, it kept saying "There was a problem loading the requested App, couldn't connect to the sever". but when i run in on web it works.

tried to start expo using local IP

Answer (score 0):

You can try remove cache

for react native

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

for expo

```
expo start -c
```